# Regex to get data after last closing brace

Tags: regex

I am looking to extract the data after the last closing brace. 
This is the test string:

```
RAID-622(00)02(88)845364758
```

My regex is:

```
\).*
```

What I have managed to get is: `)02(88)845364758`

But what I want is `845364758`

Any tips?

Comment: try `[^)]*$`..... https://regex101.com/r/gS7rL3/1

Comment: Worked. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following  regex `[^)]*$` to get string after the last `)` and at the end

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/gS7rL3/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 0):

You can search for greedy regex:

```
.*\)
```

and replace it by empty string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jQ7wP6/1)

`.*\)` will match longest string before `)` due to greedy `.*`, hence matching up to last `)` in your input text.